# moongose: reading data from mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs and moongose to work with a mongodb database. I need to read to informations basically, the field _id to get the timestamp and the field temp, one example of record:

**Mongodb record example**

```
{ _id: 57fe867e473a802218a891e0,
    _etag: 57fe867e225e107c6f47dc55,
    temp: 27875,
    coord: [ [Object] ] }
```

I'm using the following code to perform the read:

**Read code**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

mongoose.model('Temperatura',
               new Schema({ time: Number, temperature: Number}),
               'col');

var dados = mongoose.model('Temperatura');

        dados.find({}, function(err, data)
        {
                if(err){
                        console.log(err, data, data.length);
                }else{
                        console.log(data);
                }

                var Time = [];
                var Temperature = [];
                var Grafico = [];


                for ( index in data){

                  var doc = data[index];
                  var objectId = new ObjectID(doc['_id'])
                  var time = objectId.getTimestamp();
                  console.log(doc['temp']);
                  var temperature = doc['temp'];

                  Temperature.push({"value" : temperature});
                  Time.push({"value" : time});

                  }
}).sort('-date').limit(100);
```

The basic problem is that only  the `Time` array has values, the `Temperature` array presents undefined values, what is the code mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mongoose model needs to match actual data in the mongodb record. Try to add temp field into your model:

```
mongoose.model('Temperatura',
           new Schema({ time: Number, temp: Number}),
           'col');
```